# Extend SeleniumLibrary: super() method not working

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, robotframework

My automation code was initially written using Selenium2Library. Now, I want to upgrade Selenium2Library to SeleniumLibrary. The working code now showing error at super() method for SeleniumLibrary. The snippet of my code looks like this:

**Selenium2Library and Python2.7(working code)**

```
from Selenium2Library import Selenium2Library
from commonfunctions import CommonFunctions
from cs_inputs import CSInputs
from cs_buttons import CSButtons
from cs_links import CSLinks

class CSLibrary(Selenium2Library, CSInputs, CSButtons,CSLinks, CommonFunctions):
    def __init__(self, timeout=5.0, implicit_timeout=0.0, run_on_failure='Capture Page Screenshot'):
        super(CSLibrary, self).__init__()
        ....
        Selenium2Library.__init__(self,timeout=timeout,implicit_wait=implicit_timeout,run_on_failure=run_on_failure)
```

**SeleniumLibrary with Python3.7(not working)**

```
from SeleniumLibrary import SeleniumLibrary
from commonfunctions import CommonFunctions
from cs_inputs import CSInputs
from cs_buttons import CSButtons
from cs_links import CSLinks

class CSLibrary(SeleniumLibrary, CSInputs, CSButtons,CSLinks,CommonFunctions):
    def __init__(self, timeout=5.0, implicit_timeout=0.0, run_on_failure='Capture Page Screenshot'):
        super().__init__()
        ....
        SeleniumLibrary.__init__(self,timeout=timeout,implicit_wait=implicit_timeout,run_on_failure=run_on_failure)
```

**Error:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/ab/PycharmProjects/my_robotautomation/MyFramework/CSLibrary/__init__.py", line 54, in __init__
    super().__init__()
  File "/Users/ab/.local/share/virtualenvs/my_robotautomation--1kvVdI_/lib/python3.7/site-packages/SeleniumLibrary/__init__.py", line 479, in __init__
    self.event_firing_webdriver = None
  File "/Users/ab/.local/share/virtualenvs/my_robotautomation--1kvVdI_/lib/python3.7/site-packages/SeleniumLibrary/base/context.py", line 54, in event_firing_webdriver
    self.ctx.event_firing_webdriver = event_firing_webdriver
  File "/Users/ab/.local/share/virtualenvs/my_robotautomation--1kvVdI_/lib/python3.7/site-packages/robotlibcore.py", line 84, in __getattr__
    if name in self.attributes:
  File "/Users/ab/.local/share/virtualenvs/my_robotautomation--1kvVdI_/lib/python3.7/site-packages/robotlibcore.py", line 84, in __getattr__
    if name in self.attributes:
  File "/Users/ab/.local/share/virtualenvs/my_robotautomation--1kvVdI_/lib/python3.7/site-packages/robotlibcore.py", line 84, in __getattr__
    if name in self.attributes:
  [Previous line repeated 494 more times]
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

In the [Extending SeleniumLibrary](https://github.com/robotframework/SeleniumLibrary/blob/master/docs/extending/extending.rst#id1) documentation, it is mentioned that it's not possible to call the original method using super().
However, I could not find detailed documentation about how to extend SeleniumLibrary. Could anyone please help me with how to tweak the code to make it running for SeleniumLibrary?

Comment: `The working code now showing error at super() method`: Please always post the **whole error message** with **full traceback**.

Comment: Hi @Selcuk, I have updated the description.